# Image processing in matlab: rearranging operations to maximize performance in a series of convolutions?

Tags: matlab, performance, image-processing, time-complexity, convolution

I'm interested in implementing a particular problem in matlab, and I have the following code with a 'naive' implementation. I include typical values of sizes of the variables.

```
l   = 99;
m   = 21;
n   = 5;
s1  = 1024;
s2  = 1024;

H   = rand(l,l,m,m,n);  %5D Array which I have to convolve I with
I   = rand(s1,s2);      %Image

S   = zeros(s1,s2);

ind1 = cell(m,1);
ind2 = cell(m,1);

for k=1:m
    ind1{k} = k:m:s1;
    ind2{k} = k:m:s2;
end

for a=1:m
    for b=1:m
        for c=1:n
            Hs                  = squeeze(H(:,:,a,b,c));
            P                   = zeros(s1,s2);
            % this indexing operation is slow
            P(ind1{a},ind2{b})  = I(ind1{a},ind2{b});
            S                   = S + conv2(P,Hs,'same');
        end
    end
end
```

Now, I'm aware that the 2D convolution that is performed every iteration can be implemented more efficiently exploiting the convolution theorem and the fast Fourier transform, specially making use of GPU computation capabilities. However, that is still relatively slow, due partly to the indexing operation. **My question is whether there could be an implementation that reduces drastically the computational time (with more efficient memory usage, for example) compared to the naive implementation, taking into account the regularity of the projections `P`**. There are essentially the products of the image `I` with a 'comb-like' mask with a spacing of `m` that is displaced in every iteration. Also, it might be important to consider that I have to repeat this procedure for several images, but `H` is always the same.

**Edit**: I add below the `gpuArray` implementation, which is more efficient, and at the end of the day is the one I'm looking forward to improve upon.

```
function S_cpu = gpu_Implementation()

l   = 99;
m   = 21;
n   = 5;
s1  = 1024;
s2  = 1024;

H   = rand(l,l,m,m,n,'single');
I   = rand(s1,s2,'single','gpuArray');
S   = zeros(s1,s2,'single','gpuArray');

% Compute the size to which to pad arrays with zeros
exsize      = [s1, s2] + floor([l l]/2);
exsize      = 2.^nextpow2(exsize);
mc          = 1 + floor([l l]/2);
me          = mc + exsize - 1;
ind_x{1}    = 1:s1;
ind_x{2}    = 1:s2;
ind_ex{1}   = mc(1):me(1);
ind_ex{2}   = mc(2):me(2);
ind_ex{1}   = mod(ind_ex{1}-1, exsize(1)) + 1;
ind_ex{2}   = mod(ind_ex{2}-1, exsize(2)) + 1;
sadd_m      = exsize - [l,l];


for a=1:m
    ind{1}        = a:m:s1;
    for b=1:m
        ind{2}    = b:m:s2;
        for c=1:n
            Hs    = gpuArray(squeeze(H(:,:,a,b,c)));
            P     = I(ind{:});
            S     = S + conv2fft(P, ind, Hs, ind_x, ind_ex, exsize, sadd_m);
        end
    end
end

S_cpu = gather(S);

end


function y = conv2fft(x, ind, m, ind_x, ind_ex, exsize, sadd_m)

% pad with zeros the input
z         = zeros(exsize,'like',x);
z(ind{:}) = x;

% pad with zeros the mask. Now input and mask have the appropriate size
% such that circular convolution is equivalent to linear convolution
m   = padarray(m, sadd_m,'post');

% reshape the mask so the result of the convolution is the same as using
% conv2 with the option 'same'
m   = m(ind_ex{:});

% perform the convolution using the Fourier transform and the circular
% convolution theorem
y   = real(ifft2(fft2(z) .* fft2(m)));

% return the part that matches the sizes of the input
y   = y(ind_x{:});

end
```

**Edit2**: I add the run times of the cpu (first code snippet that I posted) and the gpu implementations:

```
timeit(@() cpu_Implementation())

ans =

   30.2352

gputimeit(@() gpu_Implementation())

ans =

   11.9349
```

Comment: Yes, there _could_ be such an implementation. Maybe it's straightforward, maybe it's something we haven't discovered yet, maybe it will be supported by the next generation of GPUs... On a more serious note, did you try working with `gpuArray`? Sometimes just converting your arrays to this type can help. BTW, SO is usually for questions about code that isn't working, you might also want to consider [codereview.se] in the future for questions about improvement of algorithms.

Comment: Hi, yes, I have a working `gpuArray` running that is considerably faster than the one I presented. Still, the point of the question wasn't about the implementation of the convolution itself, but about the algorithm in general and how the loops and the operations are arranged.
Do you think I should include the `gpuArray` script in the post for completion?

Comment: You should definitely mention it. You need to ask yourself - how fast would be good enough? Perhaps using gpuArrays is a "good enough" solution. Unless you have clear goals, even a re-written algorithm might not be "fast enough". I don't have experience with vectorizing convolutions, but I have a feeling that something _can_ be done to improve this situation. Just wait a bit until more people have a chance to see this... It might be helpful to give some more information about the actual problem that you're trying to solve - perhaps there are some existing optimized implementations out there.

Comment: Ok, I added it, it makes sense. As for "how fast would be good enough"? The answer is: as fast as possible. I need to iterate this procedure tens of times per image, and then run thousands of images. It is going to take many hours to run, given that I don't have access to a decent cluster.

Comment: Faster than conv2fft in GPUs is very hard. That operation is ridiculously effective on GPUs. However, have you tried profiling?   (run and time)

Comment: I did. Most of the load (>90%) it's on the conv2fft function. There, 75% of the load is on the fft operations, and the rest in zero-padding and assigning the elements from P.